# Cómo cambiar estilo del elemento padre al hacer hover sobre elemento hijo?

Tags: css

Es posible cambiar el estilo de un elemento padre con CSS cuando se hace hover sobre su elemento hijo?

Comment: Hola, Luis. No es posible

Comment: Con solo CSS, no, podrías usar javascript para hacerlo posible.

Answer (score 2):

## CSS

Sí, usando el selector `:has` sin embargo [no es soportada por ningun navegador](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

Si el caso fuera el contrario entonces sería así

```css
.parent:has(.child:hover) {
    /* Propiedades */
}
```

## Javascript

Como no es posible hacerlo con CSS puedes usar Javascript para ese caso

```js
function child_hover(child) {
    let parent = child.parentElement;
    if(!parent.classList.contains("hover_class_style"))
        parent.classList.add("hover_class_style");
}

function child_exit(child) {
    let parent = child.parentElement;
    parent.classList.remove("hover_class_style");
}
```

```css
.parent_class {
  background: gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hover_class_style {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_class">
  <button onmouseenter="child_hover(this)" onmouseout="child_exit(this)">Hover me!</button>
</div>
```

### Edit: Para hacer que funcione con todos los elementos de la misma clase

```js
function child_hover(child) {
    let parent = child.parentElement;
    if(!parent.classList.contains("hover_class_style"))
        parent.classList.add("hover_class_style");
}

function child_exit(child) {
    let parent = child.parentElement;
    parent.classList.remove("hover_class_style");
}

let childrens = document.querySelectorAll(".child_class");
childrens.forEach(el => {
    el.onmouseenter = () => child_hover(el);
    el.onmouseout = () => child_exit(el);
});
```

```css
.parent_class {
  background: gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hover_class_style {
  background: blue;
}

.child_class {
    /* Propiedades */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_class">
  <button class="child_class">Hover me!</button>
</div>
<div class="parent_class">
  <button class="child_class">Hover me!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

me parece que en todo caso tendrías que cambiar el elemento padre con hover, no al hijo por que va cambiar al hijo

entonces como tal no, pero se puede hacer con javascript algo así como

```
document.addEventListener/*es un escucha del click*/('DOMContentLoad', )

let NombreDeVariable = document.getElementsByClassName/*o en su defecto .getElementsById*/  ('NombreDelHijo')

let NombreDeOtraVariable = document.getElementsByClassName/*o en su defecto .getElementsById*/  ('NombreDelPadre')

function NombreDeLaFuncion(){

/*y lo que quieres que haga el padre*/

ejemplos

document.getElementsByClassName('VariablePuestaAlPadre').style.display = 'inline-block';

 Variable[Parametro].className += ' active';

Variable[Parametro].className.replace(" active", "");



}
```

entonces en el mismo documento html agregas a tu elemento hijo

```
onclick"NombreDeLaFuncion(ParametroDeLaFunción)"
```

Sería algo muy parecido a eso aun que javascript apenas estoy aprendiendo, no creo que funcione exactamente el codigo así pero es el ejemplo, ojala te sirva, saludos